# Wake Alexa Game skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am going to use my Game Skill in PC`s web browser. This doc page mentioned:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/web-api-for-games/alexa-games-build-your-skill.html
To notify the Alexa Service that you want to start a web app, use the Alexa.Presentation.HTML.Start directive in the Response object. Include the HTTPS link of the webpage to load onto the device. The SSL certificate must be valid for the webpage to open on an Alexa-enabled device. For more details, see Alexa.Presentation.HTML.Start.

What is the Alexa Service should be placed on my frontend?

I got SMAPI token.
Send POST https://api.amazonalexa.com/v2/skills/%s/stages/%s/invocations from my java backend. The response status code is 200 with

```
          "invocationResponse": {
                "body": {
                    "response": {
                        "shouldEndSession": false,
                        "directives": [
                            {
                                "request": {
                                    "method": "GET",
                                    "uri": "https://my-skill.html"
                                },
                                "data": {
                                    "hintSource": "hello",
                                    "someKey": "Initial start up information"
                                },
                                "configuration": {
                                    "timeoutInSeconds": 300
                                },
                                "type": "Alexa.Presentation.HTML.Start"
                            }
                        ],
                        "card": {
                            "type": "Simple",
                            "title": "HelloWorld",
                            "content": "Welcome"
                        },
                        "outputSpeech": {
                            "ssml": "<speak>Welcome</speak>",
                            "type": "SSML"
                        }
                    },
                    "userAgent": "ask-java/2.86.0 Java/1.8.0_322 templateResolver",
                    "sessionAttributes": {},
                    "version": "1.0"
                }
            },
```

But what is the next step? What is the service to parse this response and reproduce audio?